# Magento 2 : getCustomAttribute() returning Object insted of Value

Tags: magento2, customer

I am using customer repository interface, to fetch some values, of the customer.

I have added a custom attribute "Authnet_Account_Number".

I am trying to fetch the value of it by,

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$authnetAccountNumber = $customer->getCustomAttribute("authnet_account_number");
```

But when I print $authnetAccountNumber,

it is showing value "object"

Comment: Have you solved your issue or still error?

Comment: Hey solved the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can get Value of attribute by `getValue` function

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$customer->getCustomAttribute('authnet_account_number')->getValue();
```

`$customer->getCustomAttribute('authnet_account_number')` is always have object in return

i am sure it will work for you.

Comment: Not really. It can also return null

Answer (score 2):

See also using `getCustomAttribute` which is not recommended

- https://www.integer-net.com/performance-trap-magento-2-getcustomattribute-function/

Instead try

```
$authnetAccountNumber = $customer->getData('authnet_account_number');
// or
$authnetAccountNumber = $customer->getAuthnetAccountNumber();
```

Comment: Note that the original issue addressed by the blog post of integer_net is already fixed in Magento 2.3.4. The official docs mention this for system EAV attributes but also an `di.xml` change to add your custom attribute to the caching mechanism: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/attributes/